# Context.startActivity() causes lags

Tags: android, animation, android-activity, lag

I have two activities: LauncherActivity and MainActivity. MainActivity contains a map fragment, nav side bar and ConstraintLayout with UI. LauncherActivity's purpose is to provide user with login possibilities and then app init (Downloading UserInfo, FusedLocationAPI initialization to get user location before map opens and some misc operations). App init is performed in separate thread and when is done calls main thread (via Handler). While it's performing LauncherActivity shows ProgressBar. When all work is done this code is called:

```
startActivity(new Intent(LauncherActivity.this, MainActivity.class));
finish();
```

The result is when activity starts ProgressBar freezes for second and then Activity shows up with laggy animation.

How can I fix this?

**Edit 1**
I've done some testing. My code was this:

```
mLoadingTextView.setText("Loading...");
final Handler handler = new Handler();
handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        handler.removeCallbacks(this);

        mLoadingTextView.setText("Done!");
        mLoadingProgressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);

        startActivity(new Intent(LauncherActivity.this, MainActivity.class));
        finish();
    }
}, 5000);
```

The result I got: after 5 seconds of delay TextView's text changed to "Done!" and only after some second or two MainActivity openned. Is this issue caused by inflating the layout with map fragment? If so how can I fix this?

Comment: which activity is handling the progress bar? It seems like you are having issues showing the progress bar animation, so what happened between the progressbar end and the activity start.

Comment: @AndroidStorm _which activity is handling the progress bar?_ The first (LauncherActivity). ProgressBar is a view that just indicates some proccess.